# rich:suggestionBox with suggestionAction in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, seam2

I have an input with `<rich:suggestionBox>`. It works very well with a `suggestionAction` in the bean. But I want to implement this `suggestionAction` in JavaScript instead.

Here is the code of my `<rich:suggestionBox>`:

```
<h:inputText id="etabinput" />
<rich:suggestionbox height="200" width="200"
    suggestionAction="#{etablissementList.autoComplete}" var="etab" 
    for="etabinput" fetchValue="#{etab.id}    #{etab.nom}" id="suggestion" tokens=",">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{etab.type}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{etab.localite}" />
    </h:column>
    <a:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onselect">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{etab}" target="#{offreHome.instance.etablissement}"/>
    </a:support>
</rich:suggestionbox>
```

And here is the `suggestionAction()` method in my bean:

```
public List<Etablissement> autoComplete(Object o) {
    String sql =  this.getEjbql() + " where lower(etablissement.localite) like concat(lower('"+o.toString()+"'),'%')";
    return this.getEntityManager().createQuery(sql).getResultList();   
}
```

Is there a way to call the method from JavaScript without invoking the server each time?

Comment: I don't see how that's useful. With JavaScript you would need to hit the server everytime as well in order to get the suggestions. Or would you like to transfer **all** possible suggestions to JavaScript when rendering the HTML? I also don't see how it's useful as your HTML response would likely grow over 1MB or something. You've by the way a potential SQL injection hole there. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: with the actual method every time I add a character in the input a sql query starts and invoke the server.
So the proposed solution is to retrieve the list only once time in the page load and then do the filtering with a javascript method (suggestionAction)